# What does "I have never looked back" mean?

Tags: vocabulary

> Being offered that job in Las Vegas was my lucky break. I have never looked back!

What does *I have never looked back* mean?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Look back* here means that you would wonder afterwards if you made the right decision.

> When I look back at my life, I wonder if I would do things the same way...

If you say that you never looked back, it means you are so happy with the decision that you took, that you never even thought about whether it was a good decision or not afterwards.

Comment: +1 because your definition is better than [this one](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/look-back)

Answer (score 0):

I disagree.

***never look back*** is an idiomatic phrase, used mainly in Br E, but Gngram finds it in Am E, too:

> If you say that someone did something and then ***never looked back***, you mean that *they were very successful from that time on.*
>
> I went freelance when my son Adam was born, and have never looked back. ([Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/never-looked-back#:%7E:text=phrase,and%20have%20never%20looked%20back.))

It is normally used in connection with career.